# How do I add a django site to google-app-engine?

Tags: django, google-app-engine

How do I add a django site to google-app-engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the detailed way: http://uswaretech.com/blog/2009/04/develop-twitter-api-application-in-django-and-deploy-on-google-app-engine/

But that is a little old and uses django1.0.